# I'm trying to import user input variables to call upon them in another module but keep receiving an error

Tags: python

```
import math
def area(radius):
    return (math.pi * radius**2)
def circumference(radius):
    return (2 * math.pi * radius)
def main():
    radius = float(input('Enter radius of circle: '))
    ar = area(radius)
    cir = circumference(radius)
    print(f'The area of a circle with radius {radius:.2f} is {cir:.3f}')
    print(f'The circumference is {ar:.4f}')

if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

Second script: import program5_2

```
def main():
    radius = float(input('Enter radius of circle: '))
    program5_2.area()
    program5_2.circumference()
    cir = circumference(radius)
    ar = area(radius)
    print(f'The area of a circle with radius {radius:.2f} is {cir:.3f}')
    print(f'The circumference is {ar:.4f}')
main()
```

The goal is to receive the same output in second program while using imported values from first module without using classes, and I am not sure if I am going about this the correct way.
Question Prompt
"This program should import program5_2 as a module. The main function should prompt the user for the radius (as a float) and execute the imported functions. Outputs should display the same number of decimals as program5_2.py."

Comment: Hi, and welcome, what error are you receiving ? Can you your question  and add them ?

Answer (score 0):

Functions with the module prefix are called without the radius parameter:

```
program5_2.area()
program5_2.circumference()
```

You should not "import" the input values into the module, but pass them there. And I would recommend against variable names such as `cir` : 6 months from now you won't remember if is was `cir`, or `circ`.
Also there are two main() functions but that seems to be for testing purpose.